# Grabbing items from an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I want to get a list of all the objects in my S3 bucket. I've just put it in an express route application I quickly setup (doesn't really matter it's in express just what i'm comfortable with).

So i'm doing :

```
var allObjs = [];

s3.listObjects({Bucket: 'myBucket'}, function(err, data) { 

       var stringifiedObjs = JSON.stringify(allObjs);


       fs.writeFile("test", stringifiedObjs, function(err) {}) 

}
```

Which grabs my objects, stringifys them and writes them to a file called test. The issue i'm having is that it's only getting 1,000 results.

I read somewhere (I can't find where) that AWS limits you to 1,000 results per call.

How can I rerun this and grab the next 1,000? But so make sure that it's the next incremented 1,000 not still the first one?

In short, how can I get every object in my S3 bucket? I've been getting lost in the documentation.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

This is my object I get back :

```
{ Key: 'bucket_path/e11_19_9a31mv3ot51tm384grjd6rdj51boxx_q_q112.png',
    LastModified: Sat Apr 23 2016 09:16:23 GMT+0100 (BST),
    ETag: '"7d50fsdfsd4sda159b32cf85c683c5924"',
    Size: 704222,
    StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
    Owner: 
     { DisplayName: 'servers',
       ID: '58af203151c51eddf2sdfs411e0b91d274a8fda23f58280f9b06371e436f7' } },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive your response from the `listObjects` call, your response should include 2 very important fields in the `data` property:

- `IsTruncated` - True if there are more keys to return. False otherwise.
- `NextMarker` - The value to use for the `Marker` property in the next call to `listObjects`.

So after you call `listObjects`, you need to check the `IsTruncated` field to see if it's `True`. If it is, then feed the value from `NextMarker` into the value for `Marker` and call `listObjects` again.

**Update:**

It would appear that `AWS.Request` object has an `.eachPage` method which can be used to automatically make multiple calls. So there is a magical function to do this work for you.

```
var pages = 1;
s3.listObjects().eachPage(function(err, data) {
  if (err) return;
  console.log("Page", pages++);
  console.log(data);
});
```

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html

Comment: `{ IsTruncated: true,
  Marker: ' ',
  Contents: [{ myObjects }],
  Name: 'myBucket',
  Prefix: ' ',
  MaxKeys: 1000,
  CommonPrefixes: [] }`

This is the response I get back.. there's no `NextMarker` for me too call from

Comment: Ignore my previous comment cheers man! This works! The `.eachPage` you mentioned actually automatically adds the marker in for you. Sweet :D

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `marker` property as the last element of the previous get

check the documentation as reference (as you already did :) )

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html

Comment: Cheers! I had a look, my i'm super new so I got a bit lost. When i'm setting the marker, do you mean, the marker will be the last object I got from my last results?

Comment: It's a key, so you should set it to the key (usually the filename) of the last object. You can see the property list of the single object and find the `key` property

Comment: You can see an example of response here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html#RESTBucketGET-responses-examples each content has a key like this `<Key>my-third-image.jpg</Key>`

Comment: @Piertro I updated my question. So I get multiple objects back wrapped in `[ ]` if I pass through `key` as the marker, will that be the last `key` out of all my objects?

Comment: quick & dirty -> var lastKey = objects[objects.length-1].key